# Using GroupLayout

Tags: java, netbeans, grouplayout

I am trying to use GroupLayout from NetBeans 7.0, but I simply cannot select it. I did go to Properties/Libraries/Wrapped JARs/swing-layout-1.0.4.jar and even make it public but still GroupLayout still refuse to appear:

[image: setlayout]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Free design is a synonym for group layout. This layout is now in the standard java library.

Comment: Thanks ! I discover that reading the page: http://www.formdev.com/jformdesigner/doc/layouts/grouplayout/